# How to create a sorted/ranked area plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, visualization

I want to make a ranked/sorted/ordered stacked area plot in Python. This is sometimes also called a ribbon plot (because this is the name PowerBI uses) or a stream graph. Think of this as a continuous version of a stacked sorted bar chart.

Example:

[image]

Notice how the area's shift rank/order, i.e. in 1982 France overtakes Germany.

How would I implement something like this in Python? What library can I use to recreate this? i.e. matplotlib, plotly?

Comment: This type of question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.  You could create it either in matplotlib or plotly, but it will need a lot of work. See also [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/d3js/comments/4ibe5i/bump_chart/) and the links there. Apparently, this kind of "bump chart" is created by wizard Mike Bostock using his d3.js library.